# How can I turn on the iOS locationManager at a specific time and off at another time again, without the app being active? Is that possible?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, cllocationmanager

I´m trying to turn on the iOS locationManager at a specific time and then I´d like to turn it off 1 hour later after I don´t need it anymore. The whole thing should work from the background though. Is that possible?

Thanks for you help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

Your app will only remain active in the background if the apps background mode is set and the location is actively tracked.
If you stop track the location or your app goes in the background without monitoring the location your the app is suspended.